# Перестала работать отправка email не могу понять почему

Tags: php, email, файлы

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['contactFF'])) {
    $to = "my-mail@yandex.ru"; // тут стоит верный адрес проверил много раз
    $from = $_POST['contactFF'];
    $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $message = "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nТелефон: ".$_POST['phone']."\nEmail: ".$from."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF'];
    $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
    $filesize = '';
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
    $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
            $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
            $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
            $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
            $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
        }
    }
    $message.="
--$boundary--";

    if ($filesize < 20000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!';
    } else {
        echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 20 МБ.';
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<div id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="feedback-form" class="pad" action="mail.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nameFF" class="control-label">Имя</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" name="nameFF" id="nameFF" class="form-control"  placeholder="например, Иван Иванович Иванов">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contactFF" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="email" name="contactFF" id="contactFF" class="form-control"  placeholder="ivan@yandex.ru">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone" class="control-label">Телефон</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control"  placeholder="+380*********">
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fileFF" class="control-label">Прикрепить фото</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" name="fileFF[]" id="fileFF" multiple>
                    </span>
                </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="messageFF" class="control-label">Текст сообщения:</label>
            <div class="">
                <textarea id="messageFF" name="messageFF" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Информация о усопшем: 'ФИО, дата рождения-смерти, эпитафия'. Также вы можете указать номер понравившегося пейзажа 'пейзаж №', возможен индивидуальный заказ пейзажа"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input value="Отправить" type="submit" id="submitFF" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: какую ошибку возвращает функция mail() ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отправка работала и вдруг перестала, то проверяйте IP вашего сервера на попадание в DNSBL. Крайне рекомендую переделать отправку через функцию mail на отправку через сокет с авторизацией и желательно через SSL/TLS. В качестве варианта можно поднять отдельный почтовый сервер с "чистым" выделенным IP и отправлять почту через него.

Comment: Или как минимум библиотекой для отправки почты

Comment: Проблема в том что никакой ошибки код не выдавал и писал что всё замечательно. В итоге как выяснилось, проблема была связана с хостингом на котором был размещен сайт. Если кому пригодится нашел решение здесь [ссылка](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2014/05/feedback-form-file.html)